# How to fix locked Library/SourceAssetsDB file?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am collaborating with 4 other members on an unity project, when I pulled the last version of the game, I tried to open it in unity. I got an error saying "The project you are opening contains a locked Library/SourceAssetsDB file".

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7eQy.png)

I couldn't find any relevant information on the internet.

I went into the project folder to see if maybe one file is enabled on read/write-only but this was false. Here a screenshot of the project folder, I am not sure if the file "SourceAssetDB-lock" is always there, that's why I post it here.

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Rb5V.png)

Comment: Please add errors as text in the questions/answers please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)